# Why is this CSS baseline fix necessary for "inline fractions"?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I would like to use HTML+CSS to typeset something similar to an inline fraction, like:

[image: baseline ok]

I can accomplish it with the following HTML/CSS:

```css
.vstack {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.vstack > div {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
before<span class="vstack">
  <div style="top: -.5em;">high</div>
  <div style="top: .5em;">low</div>
</span>after
```

In Internet Explorer, however, it looks like this:

[image: baseline high]

or

[image: baseline low]

depending on which `div` is placed last (so far I have only seen it in IE).

Inspired by the [KaTeX project](http://khan.github.io/KaTeX/), which uses a similar approach to typeset fractions, this baseline issue can be fixed by introducing an extra `span` element:

```css
.vstack {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.vstack > div {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
}
.baseline-fix {
  display: inline-table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
before<span class="vstack">
  <div style="top: -.5em;">high</div>
  <div style="top: .5em;">low</div>
  <span class="baseline-fix"></span>
</span>after
```

(This is what KaTeX does, but `table-layout: fixed` does not seem to be necessary.)

My questions:

1. Are browsers free to interpret the spec in this regard or is IE going against it?
2. Why does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to position calculation / interpretation varying between the two browsers rendering engines.

Not a direct answer- but you should be able to accomplish the same (depending on required support) with less HTML and CSS using pseudo elements, e.g:

```css
.fraction {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.fraction:before {
  content: attr(data-top);
  position: relative;
  top: -.5em;
}
.fraction:after {
  content: attr(data-bottom);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.5em;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
before <span class="fraction" data-top="high" data-bottom="low"></span>
after
```

Or alternatively...

```css
.fraction {
  position: relative;
}
.top {
  top: -.5em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.bottom {
  top: .5em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
before
<span class="fraction">
<span class="top">high</span>
<span class="bottom">low</span>
</span>after
```

Comment: Interesting approach. This only allows text (no HTML) in the "numerator" and "denominator" though, right?

Comment: Yes- you cannot use HTML (e.g. elements etc), however you can use any (i.e. unicode) character as long as it is escaped correctly

Comment: @JanMarthedalRasmussen - alternative which allows for any content: http://jsfiddle.net/emo8vh86/4/

Comment: Except the horizontal extent seems to be determined by the 'low' element. If I replace 'high' by a longer string, it overflows into the 'after' element.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, IE is interpreting your example differently and basing the baseline for the word "after" on the word preceding it, "High". The "baseline fix" (hack) brings the baseline back to the middle.

### A different method

I have done this slightly differently.

**Tested in IE 6 - 11 and Chrome**

(IE seems to render a smaller font-size for `sub` and `sup`, if this is a problem, you can replace them with spans)

The trick is to:

- use a larger line height for the parent to control the vertical spacing between "High" and "Low". In this example, `line-height: 2em`
- wrap "high" and "low" in `<sub>` and `<sup>` and make them `display: block` so they appear over each other. ("High" and "Low" can also be wrapped in a span or div)
- wrap both high and low in a span with `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` to bring the words around it in line with its middle.

[image: Screenshot]

### Example

```css
sub,
sup {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
}
p {
  line-height: 2em;
}
p span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p class="highLow">Before<span><sup>High</sup><sub>Low</sub></span>After</p>
```